# How to change Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am developing a Blazor web app using EF, everytime I run the program, it keeps saying on the output panel:

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand (53ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT [t].[ID], [t].[AMOUNT], [t].[CREATED_DATE], [t].[DOCUMENT_NUM], [t].[PARTICULARS], [t].[USERID], [t].[USER_ID]`

`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'USERID'.`

in my Model:

```
public class TransactionModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? DOCUMENT_NUM { get; set; }
    public DateTime CREATED_DATE { get; set; }
    public string? USER_ID { get; set; }
    public EmployeeModel? USER { get; set; }
    public string? PARTICULARS { get; set; }
    public decimal AMOUNT { get; set; } }
```

I don't have a column named `USERID` and yet for some reason, EF Database Command selects a USERID

Can i manually change the EF database command? or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: EF doesn't know that the `USER_ID` column is the primary key for the `USER` object, you need to tell it

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for this, I'll try to set this back.

Answer (score 0):

This should be according to your data model. I assume the USER_ID is the foreign key for the  `EmployeeModel? USER`.

If this is, you could try below codes:

```
[ForeignKey("USER")]
public string? USER_ID { get; set; }
```

If not and there is no need to query the `public EmployeeModel? USER`, you could add below codes:

```
   [NotMapped]
    public EmployeeModel? USER { get; set; }
```